# Problem with argument type (String) -> () - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, radio-button

When I run function RadioButtonGroups I've got a following error - 'nil' is not compatible with expected argument type '(String) -> ()'
How Can I fix it?

How I run - RadioButtonGroups.init(callback: nil, selectedId: "")

Below is a code of RadioButtonGroups

```
enum TypeOfSale: String {
    case sale = "Sale"
    case change = "Change"
}

struct RadioButtonGroups: View {
    let callback: (String) -> ()
    
    @State var selectedId: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            radioSaleMajority
            radioChangeMajority
        }
    }
    
    var radioSaleMajority: some View {
        RadioButtonField(
            id: TypeOfSale.sale.rawValue,
            label: TypeOfSale.sale.rawValue,
            isMarked: selectedId == TypeOfSale.sale.rawValue ? true : false,
            callback: radioGroupCallback
        )
    }
    
    var radioChangeMajority: some View {
        RadioButtonField(
            id: TypeOfSale.change.rawValue,
            label: TypeOfSale.change.rawValue,
            isMarked: selectedId == TypeOfSale.change.rawValue ? true : false,
            callback: radioGroupCallback
        )
    }
    
    func radioGroupCallback(id: String) {
        selectedId = id
        callback(id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define default value, like

```
struct RadioButtonGroups: View {
    var callback: (String) -> () = { _ in }

    // ...
```

and now can use it as

```
RadioButtonGroups(selectedId: "")
```

Comment: Thank you, right now I've got Result of 'RadioButtonGroups' initializer is unused. Do you have any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: That's different question and answer depends on the code that uses RadioButtonGroups